# Add JavaScript var to multiple places on page

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML with 2 tags having the same name and in my JavaScript I have a `var`, so that in future if the tel number changes, it only has to be changed in one place (in the JavaScript) and will be applied to all tags with the matched named.

I can't seem to remember how to do this as I can't use 'ID' as the 'Footer' is displayed when the hidden `Div` is displayed. One is a `<p>` and the other is a `<span>` which the page contains a few of these.

It needs to be JavaScript not jQuery.

**Code**

```html
<div class="row m-0 d-flex align-items-center p-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 pr-lg-0">
        <h1>Oops, something went wrong</h1>
        <span id="otherErrorTxt" style="display: none">
            <p>This error has occurred whilst processing your request.</p>
            <p>If the error continues, please contact us on:</p>
            <p name="telNo" class="text-muted"></p> <!-- TEL NO. TO GO HERE -->
        </span>
        <span id="fourOfourTxt">
            <p>The page you are looking for is not available. This may be because of one of the following reasons:</p>
            <ul class="mb-3">
                <li>The page may have been moved or removed</li>
                <li>The page may have had its name changed</li>
                <li>You may have typed the URL incorrectly</li>
            </ul>
        </span>
        <a class="btn btn-primary col-12 col-lg-2 mt-3" href="/">Go back</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row footer">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        &copy; 2020 Packnet Limited - All rights reserved
    </div>
    <div class="col text-right">
        <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg fa-rotate-90 mr-2"></i>
        <span name="telNo"></span> <!-- TEL NO. TO ALSO GO HERE -->
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        var telNo = '01234 567 8900 (8.30am till 5.30pm - Mon to Fri excluding bank holidays)';

        if (document.getElementById('returnedError').innerHTML.indexOf('404') != -1) {
            document.getElementById('fourOfourTxt').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('otherErrorTxt').style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('fourOfourTxt').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('otherErrorTxt').style.display = 'block'
        }

        document.getElementsByName('telNo').innerHTML = telNo; // Not working
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `<p>` and `<span>` elements can have "name" attributes but they don't mean anything. You should instead give them a class and then use `document.getElementsByClassName()` or `document.querySelectorAll()` to find them.

Comment: Also, note that getElements* return a collection of elements. You can’t just call ‘innerHTML =‘ on the return value. You have to iterate over each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the results of the `getElementsByName()` function since it returns a collection. See example below. As mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't use name on span elements. It's better to use a class selector instead. The same logic applies for the `getElementsByClassName()` or `querySelectorAll()` functions since these return collections as well.

```js
var telNo = '01234 567 8900 (8.30am till 5.30pm - Mon to Fri excluding bank holidays)';

document.getElementsByName('telNo').forEach((el) => {
  el.innerHTML = telNo;
});
```

```html
<div class="row m-0 d-flex align-items-center p-5">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 pr-lg-0">
    <h1>Oops, something went wrong</h1>
    <span id="otherErrorTxt" style="display: block">
            <p>This error has occurred whilst processing your request.</p>
            <p>If the error continues, please contact us on:</p>
            <p name="telNo" class="text-muted"></p> <!-- TEL NO. TO GO HERE -->
        </span>
    <span id="fourOfourTxt">
            <p>The page you are looking for is not available. This may be because of one of the following reasons:</p>
            <ul class="mb-3">
                <li>The page may have been moved or removed</li>
                <li>The page may have had its name changed</li>
                <li>You may have typed the URL incorrectly</li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    <a class="btn btn-primary col-12 col-lg-2 mt-3" href="/">Go back</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row footer">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    &copy; 2020 Packnet Limited - All rights reserved
  </div>
  <div class="col text-right">
    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-lg fa-rotate-90 mr-2"></i>
    <span name="telNo"></span>
    <!-- TEL NO. TO ALSO GO HERE -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much I was going out my mind, I knew it could be done just could not for the life of me remember how as I don't normally use the name